# MDX how retrieve first order date as a dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, dimensions

How to create a `dimension` that would group users by the date of the first order.

Example initial table:

```
UserId | OrderDate | OrderAmount
1        2012        100    
1        2013        100    
2        2013        100    
2        2014        100
```

Retrieving the first order date is fairly easy

```
FILTER([Date].[OrderDate].MEMBERS, [Measures].[OrderAmount]).ITEM(0).NAME
```

But how create a `dimension` so the result rows would be grouped by the date of first order.

OrderDate

First order date
(orders)
    xxxx   2012 2013    2014

2012           100

2013           100  100 100

Comment: Problem solved by using NamedCalculation in DSV :)

Comment: FYI: I think `FILTER` is a very inefficient way of retrieving the first order date. The second argument you use in filter - `[Measures].[OrderAmount]` - is there an implied logical expression?